# Magento changes in the url the symbol "?" by "#21%"

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

When I select the order or the number of items to display in the toolbar, Magento shows in the url "# 21%" instead of "?"

It should be "productoslist.html?limit=30", but is "productoslisthtml.html#%21limit=30"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Ok, no problem. I dont know If is a programming problem, the url comes from getOrderUrl()

Comment: You could certainly put the code for `getOrderUrl()` and show that this is where the problem lies. Then it would be about programming and we could help fix it.

Comment: Do you know where is the function getOrderUrl()?, thanks in advice